# ScalaFX and Akka (View message Actor)

Tags: akka, scalafx

Taking from [Mucaho's Scalatrix](https://bitbucket.org/mucaho/scalatrix/overview) example I'd like to send messages from the View (ScalaFX) to the `controller` actor, how can I abstract/expose the actor to be able to do this?

```html
object Ops extends App {

  override def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    new JFXPanel(); // trick: create empty panel to initialize toolkit
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      override def run(): Unit = {
        View.main(Array[String]())
      }
    }).start()

    val system = ActorSystem("Ops")
    val controller = system.actorOf(Props[Controller], "controller")
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking here. From the `ActorSystem`, you can always obtain a reference to any actor therein, using the method [`actorSelection(path: String)`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.3.9/?_ga=1.251897226.2043915.1425983990#akka.actor.ActorSystem) and passing the name path you gave to the actor (i.e. `"controller"`)

Comment: For the record, which version of akka/scala are you using?

Comment: @pagoda_5b I could instantiate the ActorSystem from within the View as follows:

`object View extends JFXApp {

  val system = ActorSystem("Ops")
  val controller = system.actorOf(Props[Controller], "controller")

  stage = new PrimaryStage {
    title = "Ops"
    width = 800
    height = 600
    minWidth = 800
    minHeight = 600

    scene = {...}
  }
}`

but not sure how I'd be able to access it from the View if the ActorSystem was defined as in my inital post?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that comes to my mind at the moment is to wrap the system and actors as publicly accessible members of another object

```html
object Ops extends App {

  override def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    new JFXPanel(); // trick: create empty panel to initialize toolkit
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      override def run(): Unit = {
        View.main(Array[String]())
      }
    }).start()

    object Actors {
      val system = ActorSystem("Ops")
      val controller = system.actorOf(Props[Controller], "controller")
    }
  }
}
```

now you can send messages in any part of your code, *e.g.*

```
object View extends JFXApp {
  stage = ...

  Ops.Actors.controller ! Tick
}
```